# SharePoint 2013 Search Results Issue

Tags: sharepoint-search

We took a backup of our production content DB and restored in lower environment.  Then we did a search index reset, and full crawl.  But when using Search API (REST) calls, the results seem old results and does not take into consideration the new content DB.

Would search results be cached somewhere when called from Search API?  When using the QueryBuilder, we find the search results are coming up correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your anonymous search results cache

Answer (score 1):

Is Anonymous Authentication enabled for your sites? If yes, disable and then enable anonymous authentication, then reset index followed by a full crawl. This will update Anonymous Search Results Cache.